# Screenshot from service on rooted device

Tags: java, android, screenshot, root, rooted-device

I am trying to write code that captures the screen 50 times from a service on a rooted device and saves the pictures in a folder. How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
for (int i=0; i < 50; i++)
{
    os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/pics/img" +i+".png").getBytes("ASCII"));
    os.flush();
    sh.waitFor();
}

os.close();
```

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?